# Eclipse huge CPU spikes

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, jvm, jvisualvm

I am desperately trying to find the issue of my Eclipse to freeze for moments (up to 2-3 sec) caused by CPU spiked (18-19 cores with 100% load). During the spikes nothing works, whole eclipse just unresponsive.
Life got better since I modified `eclipse.ini` to use proper heap size and garbage collector. Nevertheless, freezes are still present. I have used `jvisualvm` to rule out garbage collector. As you can see on the screen below, there is no dependency between CPU spikes and heap size.

**Could you please advise me how I can identify the issue (CPU spikes) by using either `jvisualvm` or any other tool avaliable for Linux?**

---

Tech details:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

[image: Spikes in CPU]

```
$ cat /opt/eclipse/eclipse.ini
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-showsplash org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Xss2M
-Xms3G
-server
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M

-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapWastePercent=5
-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=83
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500
```

---

Full thread dump [here](https://gist.github.com/cronacronis/136408b858724d848cdc)

Most suspicious thread:

```
  "RJHelper [Thread-1]" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fe128009000 nid=0xe37a waiting for monitor entry [0x00007fe13f5f9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:172)
    - locked <0x00000003a4539c40> (a java.util.ArrayList)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.runAsync(Unknown Source)
    at de.walware.rj.server.client.AbstractRJComClient.runAsyncPing(AbstractRJComClient.java:754)
    at de.walware.rj.server.client.AbstractRJComClient$KeepAliveRunnable.run(AbstractRJComClient.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x000000039a4ee240> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Comment: One of the catches of the Eclipse IDE is how many temp things you have done. For instance see how many breakpoints you have setted, how many unittests have you run. Clear all consoles and all that views (junit, coverage, local history, search) and test it again. Or it maybe related to some installed plugin.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I have tried all obvious things. Now I am the point where I have to find the issue in a more precise way.

Comment: I've not used Eclipse on Linux but I've experienced this kinds of freezes a lot, much of then were related to the things I said. I don't know a tool to do that, between this question `asking about a tool` is off-topic here. Another thing that sometimes happens was related with the builds of some projects. Some projects using maven or ant with lots of resources  can freeze eclipse sometimes. Check your projects and your builds. Disable the automatic build and see if it still freeze, if not it is a build related problem then you go from there.

Comment: Trigger a thread dump next time it happens. Have the `kill -3 PID` ready in a separate window so that you can trigger it as soon as Eclipse becomes unresponsive (nb, not "irresponsible").

Comment: @kdgregory I have added Thread dump, there are some threads blocked. But it doesn't really clarify the issue ;(

Comment: Blocked threads won't cause a CPU spike. Look for the ones that are running.

Answer (score 1):

Jvisualvm also supports threaddumps and even thread dump based profiling,which should help you to identify what is going on quickly.